# how to use a loop variable in a regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to iterate over a list of dicts(keys:labelname and id)  and want to get the string after the label value using regex

```
text = "Company Name: ABC \n Address: 123St, LA \n Post Code: 12345 \n"
const itemList = [
  { id: 'companyName', label: 'Case or Reference Id' },
  { id: 'companyaddress', label: 'Address' },
  { id: 'companyPostcode', label: 'Post Code' }
];
for (let i = 0; i < itemList.length; i++) {
      let caseRegex = /(?<=${itemList[i].label}: )\w+/g;
      let regexStr = caseRegex.exec(text);
      console.log("regexStr",regexStr);
};
```

It works when I try the string as it is. But I not able to get the above work using variable from loop

```
for (let i = 0; i < itemList.length; i++) {
      let caseRegex = /(?<=Company Name: )\w+/g;
      let regexStr = caseRegex.exec(text);
      console.log("regexStr",regexStr);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the `RegExp` constructor to create a dynamic regular expression. You can use a template literal to interpolate variables into the string.

```js
let caseRegex = new RegExp(`(?<=${itemList[i].label}: )\w+`, 'g');
```

Note that you may need to escape regular expression metacharacters when constructing the `RegExp`.